# jquery modal loading php in a div

Tags: jquery, load, modal-dialog

this is in a php loop;

```
echo "<td><a id='gbdetail' href='#gbdetay' data-toggle='modal' onClick='getGBdetay()' class='btn btn-small' data-original-title=' click to see detail ' data-placement='left' rel='tooltip' href2='lookgb.php?gbid=".$wrgb['id']."'>"."<i class='gicon-edit'></i></a></td>";
```

and this is jquery part;

```
function getGBdetay()  { 
    $('#gbdetail').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href2'); 
        $("#gbbody").load(url); 
    }); 
};
```

it works only for first row, content doesnt loading in other rows. what can cause this?

**Edit:**

it worked with changing selector. but now it doesnt work on first click. on first click content doesnt loading. after first click it works without problem. why doesnt it working on first click?

```
    function getGBdetay()  { 
  $('.btn.btn-small.gbdetayl').click(function(){
   var url = $(this).attr('href2');
   $("#gbbody").load(url);
});

 echo "<td><a target='_blank' href='#gbdetay' data-toggle='modal'  onClick='getGBdetay()' class='btn btn-small gbdetayl' data-original-title=' click to see detail ' data-placement='left' rel='tooltip' href2='lookgb.php?gbid=".$wrgb['id']."'>"."<i class='gicon-edit'></i></a></td>";
```

Comment: `<a id='gbdetail'` You can only have one html element with any given id. id's must be unique, if that's in a loop it means you have several anchor links with the id `gbdetail`. Try making it a class

Comment: It would help if you would post the rendered HTML.  This is not really a PHP problem.

Comment: Please don't trash your question and remove all the content. It stops it from being useful to other people. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can only IDs once in the page.

You can give the `<a>`s the same class instead of the same ID and then you can use that to select all elements on. You have used `btn` as class so you can do

```
function getGBdetay()  { 
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href2'); 
        $("#gbbody").load(url); 
    }); 
};
```

Every button will then have this onclick function. It might be needed to add another class or another way to select all links.

Comment: Yes. As said, `id`s should be unique in the page. An `id` can only be used on one HTML element in that page. You made all your `<a>`s have the same IDs. And that's why your script only gave one element back.

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe because href2 is not an official attribute. You should use the HTML5 data- attribute prefixer to do such things IMO. instead of href2 you should do `data-href2` for example. I think that might work, but else I don't know. You could make a jsfiddle to show us the code running.

Comment: Can you provide a full HTML output of the php for loop?

Comment: Hmm, I've checked it but can't find any obvious errors. I'm sorry :/